# Flutter Audio Editing SDK

Tags: flutter, audio, editing, audiotrack

I am looking for an SDK which supports Audio editing features.

The features I am looking for are as below

- Audio Trimming
- Audio Splitting
- Audio Volume management
- Adding another audio
- Merge Audio
- Undo/Redo actions

Please suggest if there are any sdks avaialble for flutter.

I am currently implementing it using ['ffmpeg_kit_flutter'](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter) , but its getting complicated day by day.

Comment: Please see #3 of [help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

There may not be a single package that does all the functions you want. But it is possible to achieve results by combining several packages.

The **most popular packages** for working with **Audio** can be found on the following site: https://fluttergems.dev/audio/

For example, it is possible to **trim** and **split** with the packages listed in the first line.